# When using KeyListener - 2 input happens

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I am programing 2D rpg game and I have weird problem. When I use KeyPressed method it happens to call my move method twice which exits to rewrite player position from [10,10] to [10,12] insted of [10,11] and move my player 2 fields. I was looking around the internet and found nothing useful.

For displaying I use Canvas and Runnable with JFrame. A also use Thread

When I used debugger to search what's wrong I found that Keylistener use method 
KeyPressed

```
   public  void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
{
        ((KeyListener)a).keyPressed(e);
        ((KeyListener)b).keyPressed(e);
}
```

I believe that KeyListener a and b do the problem but I dont know hot to fix it.

My move method which change Point (x,y)

```
  public void move() {
    Point startPlayerPosition = player.getPosition();
    Point newPoint = startPlayerPosition;
    switch (direction) {

        case Direction.NORTH:
            newPoint = new Point(startPlayerPosition.x, startPlayerPosition.y - 1);
            break;
        case Direction.SOUTH:
            newPoint = new Point(startPlayerPosition.x, startPlayerPosition.y + 1);
            break;
        case Direction.WEST:
            newPoint = new Point(startPlayerPosition.x - 1, startPlayerPosition.y);
            break;
        case Direction.EAST:
            newPoint = new Point(startPlayerPosition.x + 1, startPlayerPosition.y);
            break;
    }
    playerPos = newPoint;
    player.setPosition(newPoint);}
```

This is my KeyPressed method. I wait for pressing W,A,S,D to to change direction and then I call move() according to direction.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_W:
            playerWalk = true;
            direction = Direction.NORTH;
            move();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_S:
            playerWalk = true;
            direction = Direction.SOUTH;
            move();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_D:
            playerWalk = true;
            direction = Direction.EAST;
            move();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_A:
            playerWalk = true;
            direction = Direction.WEST;
            move();
            break;
    }
}
```

Thanks for Help

Comment: what are `a` and `b`?

Comment: It is in internal method in AWTEventMulticaster.java I cant change it or work without it.